# Sort matrix according to all rows in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix `M` with many rows that I would like to sort such that the order of rows within a column is fixed, but that the columns are reordered.

I know that I could achieve this with code like this:

`M[,order(M[1,],M[2,],M[3,],M[4,])]`

but how do I generalize this code so that it works for more than 4 rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can convert to `data.frame` and use `do.call` with `order`

```
res <- M[,do.call(order, as.data.frame(t(M))[1:4])]
#OP's code
res2 <- M[,order(M[1,],M[2,],M[3,],M[4,])]
identical(res, res2)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
set.seed(1)
M <- matrix(sample(1:25), 5, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not quite the desired outcome. This permutes the order of rows within a column.

Comment: @Student It gives the same output as your code.  Please check with the example I showed

Comment: Ah! Adding the t(M) seems to have fixed it. Thank you very much!